# Scroll to a specific <img> or <a> tag when I hit the search button on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, scroll

As the title says, I want the page to scroll down to an image when I search for it on my search bar.

This is the HTML for the search bar/button:

```
<form id="search-form" href="#test1" class="smoothscroll">
    <input type="text" id="searchText"/>
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="searchButton"/>
</form>
```

This is the `<img>` and `<div>` tag I'm trying to scroll to:

```
<a href="test1.html" style="text-decoration: none">
    <img src="pic1.png" height="150px" width="150px"/>
    <img src="pic2.png" id="id1"/>
</a>
```

And here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#searchButton" ).click(function() {
        //var text = document.getElementById('searchText').value;
        $( "html, body" ).animate({     
            scrollTop: ($('#test1').offset().top)
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

I keep getting this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: The message indicates that `offset()` returned `undefined`, which indicates that `$('#test1')` didn't select anything, which indicates that you don't have an element with the id `test1`. And indeed, I don't see that element in the snippet your posted.

Comment: `#test1` doesn't exist.

Comment: Please add "ID=test1" to any of your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `id="test1"` to your required image. or use `$("a[href*='test1']:first").offset().top`

Answer (score 0):

There is no `$('#test1')` in your HTML.  The jQuery selector `#test1` looks for an element with an `id` of "test1".  Try adding that `id` to your `a`:

```
<a id="test1" href="test1.html" style="text-decoration: none">
```

Also, I don't think `href="#test1"` is a valid attribute for a `form` tag.  It's not being used for anything, so you probably don't need it.  (The form's `class` attribute is also probably superfluous, and could technically be invalid.  You'll want to [validate your markup](http://validator.w3.org/) to make sure of these things.)

Answer (score 0):

Please add "id=1" to any of your images.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an ID to that anchor, otherwise you could technically do:

```
$('a[href="test1.html"]')
```

I'd still recommend giving it an `id="test1'`

Answer (score 0):

Test if $("#test1").length is > 0 before the animate() call. This could just be fixing the symptom and not the underlying problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this.

HTML:

```
<form id="search-form" href="#test1" class="smoothscroll">
    <input type="text" id="searchText"/>
    <input type="button" value="Search" id="searchButton"/>
</form>

<a style="margin-top: 1000px; display: inline-block;" href="test1.html" style="text-decoration: none">
    <img src="pic1.png" id="image1" />
    <img src="pic2.png" id="image2"/>
</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#searchButton" ).click(function() {

    var text = $('#searchText').val().toLowerCase();

    $( "html, body" ).animate({     
        scrollTop: ($('#'+text).offset().top)
    }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Here is the [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/agT98/). I've added a large margin to the `<a>` link to see the scrolling effect.